# C# Xml Value always getting null

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have the following Xml in my Resources.xmltest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>   
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://DFISofft.com/SmartPayments/">
    <Result>0</Result>
    <Message>Pending</Message>
    <PNRef>222131</PNRef>
    <ExtData>InvNum=123</ExtData>   
 </Response>
```

I've tried several ways to get the values, Result,Message,PNRef,ExtData, out of it and I've had no luck. I always get a null value for the NodePath so it never goes into the loop:

```
  var XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

  XmlDoc.LoadXml(Resources.xmltest);
  XmlElement NodePath = (XmlElement) XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Response");

  while (NodePath != null)
  {
    foreach (XmlNode Xml_Node in NodePath)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(Xml_Node.Name + " " + Xml_Node.InnerText);
    }
  }
```

I've tried this:

```
  XmlNode node3 = XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("PNRef");
  Console.WriteLine(node3.Value);

  Console.WriteLine(XmlDoc.InnerXml);

  var tst = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("PNRef");
  Console.WriteLine(tst);
```

And this:

```
  NodePath = (XmlElement) XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Response");

  if (NodePath != null)
  {
    foreach (XmlNode node in NodePath)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("NodeName: " + Xml_NodeX.Name);
      Console.WriteLine("NodeValue: " + node.InnerText);
    }
   }
```

Apparently, I'm not getting the xml read/write. I've done it with DataSets but they do all the work for you.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I've been at this for longer than I should have been already.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick and great answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the node isn't called response; you need to take the namespace into account:

```
var XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(XmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://DFISofft.com/SmartPayments/");
XmlDoc.LoadXml(yourXml);
XmlElement NodePath = (XmlElement)XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/x:Response", nsmgr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your XML has a **XML namespace** and you're not paying any attention to it:

```
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
          xmlns="http://DFISofft.com/SmartPayments/">
          ******************************************
```

When selecting from this XML, you need to use that XML namespace!

You're not taking into account the XML namespace (`xmlns="http://nts-de-osm1-pxc/webservices/"`) on the document!

Try this:

```
 var XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

 // setup the XML namespace manager
 XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(XmlDoc.NameTable);

 // add the relevant namespaces to the XML namespace manager
 mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://DFISofft.com/SmartPayments/"); 

 XmlDoc.LoadXml(Resources.xmltest);

 // **USE** the XML anemspace in your XPath !!
 XmlElement NodePath = (XmlElement) XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Response");

  while (NodePath != null)
  {
    foreach (XmlNode Xml_Node in NodePath)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(Xml_Node.Name + " " + Xml_Node.InnerText);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your XPath query, which doesn't specify a namespace - despite the fact that your document only has a `Response` element in the "http://DFISofft.com/SmartPayments/" namespace. Ditto the `PNRef` elements.

Personally I'd use LINQ to XML if I *actually* wanted to use namespaces if at all possible. For example:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://DFISofft.com/SmartPayments/";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

foreach (var element in doc.Descendants(ns + "PNRef"))
{
    // Use element here
}
```

As you can see, LINQ to XML makes it really easy to use namespaces - but of course it requires .NET 3.5 or higher. If I had to use .NET 2.0, I'd either use `XmlNamespaceManager` or iterate manually and check local names instead of using XPath.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference...

[Bubba Soft](http://www.bubasoft.net/) 
This site has a great free tool for building XPath Expressions (XPath Builder).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using the overload of `SelectSingleNode` that assumes an empty namespace.  Since you have a default namespace you will need to use the version that takes an XmlNamespaceManager.  [See this article for more info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx.aspx)

from the docs:

> If the XPath expression does not include a prefix, it is assumed that the namespace URI is the empty namespace. If your XML includes a default namespace, you must still add a prefix and namespace URI to the XmlNamespaceManager; otherwise, you will not get a node selected. For more information, see Select Nodes Using XPath Navigation.